# EAI_AGAIN issue in kubernetes for redis connection

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

i am connecting redis in node js and I am able to connect on local . i have deploy code on kubernates and try connect redis its gives error

{"errno":"EAI_AGAIN","code":"EAI_AGAIN","syscall":"getaddrinfo","hostname":"redis-19521.c89.us-east-1-3.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com","host":"redis-19521.c89.us-east-1-3.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com","port":19521}